# uint showing in hexadecimal in console

Tags: web3js

Simple issue but couldn't find solution. When I run a console to interact with a function that returns uint in a smart contract, it shows in hexadecimal notation. Like this:

`<BN: a>`
(meaning the value 10 in decimal)

How do I specify the output format so I can see the value in decimal?
I don't think it's necessary for that matter, but the coding is as follows:

```
uint dist;
function getDist() public view returns (uint distancia){
    return dist;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shared your JavaScript code, but presumably you're just logging the `BN` directly? Try calling `.toString()` on whatever variable holds the `BN`.

Comment: I've found that `.toString()` takes a parameter, that's why it wasn't working for me before. Thanks.

Comment: What version of web3.js are you using, and what parameter did you need to pass to `.toString()`?

Comment: web3.js 1.0.0 uses this bn.js, where you should be able to call `.toString()` without any parameters to get the default behavior of base 10 with no extra padding: https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/blob/master/lib/bn.js#L447

Comment: '1.0.0-beta.37'. The parameter was the representation desired. 10 for decimal. So I did: `contractInstance.getDist().then(function(x){console.log(x.toString(10))})
` and it worked

Comment: You're right, 10 is default and so it works too. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

I don't think returning decimal from Solidity function is supported at the moment. The reason is using hex-decimal saves more space than decimal when transmitting data. The conversation from hex to other formats like string or decimal needs to happen at front-end either manually or via a js library.